# Reshaping Data in R vs python

Tags: python, r, reshape

I'm trying to restructure a data-frame in R for k-means. Presently the data is structured like this:

```
 Subject Posture   s1 s2 s3....sn
  1       45       45 43 42 ...
  2       90       35  45 42 ..   
  3        0        3   56 98
  4        45       ....
```

and so on. I'd like to collapse all the sn variables into a single column and create an additional variable with the s-number:

```
 Subject Posture sn dv 
 1       45       1 45 
 2       90       2 35    
 3        0       3  31 
 4        45      4  45
```

Is this possible within R, or am I better off reshaping the csv directly in python?
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: collapse how? mean? median? sum? R is perfect for this sort of work but you need to be more specific.

Comment: I'm confused by your example and don't see how the two relate to one another. Can you provide an exact mapping for say 3 rows and s1-s3?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the typical approach in base R (though using "reshape2" is probably the more typical practice).

Assuming we're starting with "mydf", defined as:

```
mydf <- data.frame(Subject = 1:3, Posture = c(45, 90, 0),  
    s1 = c(45, 35, 3), s2 = c(43, 45, 56), s3 = c(42, 42, 98))
```

You can reshape with:

```
reshape(mydf, direction = "long", idvar=c("Subject", "Posture"), 
        varying = 3:ncol(mydf), sep = "", timevar="sn")
#        Subject Posture sn  s
# 1.45.1       1      45  1 45
# 2.90.1       2      90  1 35
# 3.0.1        3       0  1  3
# 1.45.2       1      45  2 43
# 2.90.2       2      90  2 45
# 3.0.2        3       0  2 56
# 1.45.3       1      45  3 42
# 2.90.3       2      90  3 42
# 3.0.3        3       0  3 98
```

Comment: Something like `data.frame(mydf[1:2],stack(mydf[-(1:2)]))` will also work fine too.

Answer (score 3):

```
require(reshape2)
melt(df, id.vars="Posture")
```

Where `df` is the data.frame you presented.  Next time please use dput() to provide actual data.

I think this will work for you.

EDIT:

Make sure to install the reshape2 package first of course.

Comment: This seems like the right idea. However I'd like to keep all variables intact except the s1...sn variables